# Кулич и паска? Почему возникли варианты?

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Не так давно узнала, что пасхальное блюдо "кулич" на юге России и на Украине называют "паска". В России же "пасха" — творожное пасхальное блюдо. Украинский вариант (судя по Вики) встречается у молдаван, румын и цыган.

Как кулич называют в Белоруссии, Польше?

Кстати, в российской песочнице дети лепят куличики, используя для этого формочки, украинские — лепят пасочки (формочки называют тоже пасочками).

Comment: После долгой зимы и вынужденного длительного поста наступала весна, начинали зеленеть пастбища и приходил Великдень. Отступала угроза голодной смерти и люди воочию видели свое спасение.
В классической латыни и русском языке полное совпадение смыслов :

pasco - пасти, кормить, питать, съедать;
pascor - пастись, кормиться, поедать траву;
pascua - пастбище.

Молодые ягнята выходили на свежую травку, начиналась новая жизнь!
Еврейское значение (Песах - *мимо прошел*) вполне можно отнести к прошедшему неблагоприятному и голодному сезону. Зима кончилась - пришла *паска*, спасение. Ежегодный праздник

Comment: Я в детстве всегда говорила пасКа, а не пасХа. И играла в пасочки. Слово "кулич" впервые встретила в художественной литературе и не знала, ЧТО это. Х
лебные паски даже в советские времена продавались в магазинах, только назывались типа "кекс Юбилейный" . На западной Украине творожные пасхи не делались,я впервые прочитала о них в книге Е.Молоховец, очень хотелось приготовить, но не было формочек. Сейчас многие готовят творжные пасхи, но дома. В продаже не видела, так как они быстро портятся. Разве что в маленьких кондитерских или ресторанах. Но формочки для них продаются вовсю.

Comment: Пасха - это избавление, спасение от смерти, от беды, от всего злого. Жертвенного ягнёнка Пасхой не называли, для него в Библии есть другие слова. А называть ХЛЕБ Пасхой - это по меньшей мере бессмысленно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сдаётся мне, что это не языковые варианты, а речевые. В русском языке кулич и пасха - это не одно и то же. Кулич – это сдобный пасхальный пирог, хлеб, а пасха - это пасхальный  творожный десерт. Пирог на Пасху символизирует то, как Христос вкушал со своими учениками хлеб. Это символ Воскресения Иисуса.

Пасхой  в Библии назывался совсем не пирог и не творог, а агнец или ягненок. Он символизировал жертву Христа. Постепенно от идеи жертвы отошли, стали заменять другими яствами-символами, творожной пасхой, например.Наши традиции причудливым образом сочетают христианство и язычество.Воскресение Христа совпало с весенним возрождением и стало символом вообще возрождения.Творог в древности символизировал плодородие, его часто использовали в различных обрядах, связанных с весенним приветствия земли. Сам творог считался больше, чем просто едой. Он включает в себя все самое ценное и питательное для человека, что есть в молоке. Блюдо готовили раз в году, и поэтому делалось оно очень долго и из самых лучших продуктов.Творожная пасха (в Требнике – млеко огустевшее, то есть творог) имеет форму усеченной пирамиды, что символизирует гроб, в котором совершилось величайшее чудо Воскресения. 
Практически все пасхальные традиции возникли в богослужении. Даже размах пасхальных народных гуляний связан с разговением после Великого поста — времени воздержания, когда все праздники, семейные в том числе, переносились на празднование Пасхи. Символами Пасхи становится всё, что выражает Обновление (Пасхальные ручьи), Свет (Пасхальный огонь), Жизнь (Пасхальные куличи, яйца, творог  и зайцы).
Сегодня творожная пасха потеряла свое языческое значение. Ее именуют «благословенной пищей». Творог символизирует мечту и сладкую жизнь в небесах. А сам белый цвет символизирует смерть и воскресение в новой жизни. [ПАСХАЛЬНЫЕ БЛЮДА ИЛИ ПОЧЕМУ ПЕКУТ КУЛИЧИ И КРАСЯТ ЯЙЦА | eat.by](http://eat.by/articles/easter-pies-and-colored-eggs.aspx)

В древности высокий хлеб с яйцами символизировал бога плодородия. Получается, что оба блюда похожи и по форме, и по символическому значению, значит, взаимозаменяемы.Пасхальный творог - пасха и пасхальный пирог - пасха. Зачем произносить два слова, когда можно коротко - пасха. Так и стал кулич, т.е. пирог, пасхой.

Comment: >Сдаётся мне, что это не языковые варианты, а речевые.   
  
А что это вообщк такое - и в чем между ними разница?

>Пасхой в Библии назывался совсем не пирог и не творог, а агнец или ягненок   

Даже комментировать не хочется. Ягненоу - это агнец. А пасха - Пейсах.

Comment: Языковой вариант - нормативная лексика, зафиксированная в академических словарях, речевой вариант - разговорный (диалектизм, профессионализм, арго, просторечие). Пасхальную жертву называли корбан пейсах. Если Пасха от Пейсах, почему бы и этому названию не перейти в русский, только не в качестве жертвы, а в качестве пасхальной пищи? Поначалу ведь жертву и ели. А пирог, кекс, хлеб - одно и то же в смысле символа. Когда "хлеб и соль"подают, хлеб - и в виде каравая,и в виде кекса, и в виде буханки-кирпичика, это же символ.

Comment: Кули́ч (греч. κουλλίκι(ον) из ср.-греч., от κόλλιξ «хлеб круглой или овальной формы») — обрядовый хлеб у славян, непременный атрибут пасхального стола. Название кулич церковного происхождения, пришедшее в русский язык из греческого, в котором оно означает «крендель»(Википедия).

Comment: По поводу южно-русских(украинских) диалектизмов.Общеизвестно,думаю, что литературный украинский язык создан усилиями энтузиастов путем введения в норму как раз региональных диалектизмов и просторечных вариантов(вначале), а впоследствии насыщения его терминами из нерусских языков(польского,немецкого,вульгарной латыни и др.)Благодаря большевистской политике "коренизации"(украинизации населения УССР)сейчас "мова" - уже не потешное наречие, а вполне полноценный язык с миллионами носителей.

Answer (score 4):

**Кулич** - по-украински *ПАС**К**А*- *сладкий сдобный высокий хлеб* цилиндрической формы (по православному обычаю такой хлеб выпекается ко дню Пасхи).

**Пас**х**а** - по-украински *СИРНА ПАС**К**А* - сладкое *кушанье из творога* в форме небольшой четырёхгранной пирамиды, изготовляемое к дню этого христианского праздника.

А сам праздник ПАСХА - по-украински ВЕЛИКДЕНЬ (в народе говорят Паска).

Вот так говорят **в центральной части Украины**.

Comment: Сирна паска - да, тоже слышал. Не знал, что это распространено. Спасибо.
Остальное - понятно.

Comment: >Сирна паска - да, тоже слышал.

А кто-нибудь эту сырну паску *видел* на Украине ? В энциклопедии я тоже о ней читал. Поймите правильно, я не спорю, совсем нет. Просто интересно.

В продаже в магазинах обычные паски из сдобного теста видел много раз. На этикетке так и написано *"Паска"* . Я, конечно, мог что-то и пропустить, этот праздник раз в году, и паски в остальное время просто не встречаются. Разве что, как заметила автор вопроса, у детей в песочнице, как *пасочки*.

Comment: Хороший, интересный вопрос. Автору +1.

Comment: @Nikolja, я и в России пасху (блюдо) никогда в продаже не встречал. Связано это по всей видимости с очень коротким сроком годности данного продукта.

Comment: Для тех, кому действительно интересно. Сырных пасок, я так думаю, никто до этого времени в магазинах не видел. Их просто на продажу не делают, потому что эти пасхальные изделия не поддаются тепловой обработке, а значит, быстро портятся. Тем более что главным ингредиентом этого пасхального  блюда является творог. А где его настоящего взять-то в таком колличестве? Делают в основном сырные паски в селах, с дом. творогом, изюмом и т. д. Но, наверное, они не возродятся так, как собственно паски. Потому мы о них и знаем из справочной литературы.

Comment: Ну вот, а я в этом году впервые сделала пасху из творога! По телевизору увидела рецепт, сейчас же много кулинарных передач.

Answer (score 3):

~1.
Ну почему возникли - это опять вопрос без ответа. Так уж сложилось.

Вопрос, имхо, надо ставить, к одному ли корню восходит "пасха" и "паска", или же это случайное созвучие. Я думаю, что все-таки первое. "Пасха" в этом значении означает "главное пасхальное блюдо", а конкретное наполнение разошлось. На юге России и Украине подобную творожную массу не очень уважают, и Пасха стала ассоциироваться с куличом.

Но не уверен.

*Не поверите, сам хотел этот вопрос задать. Потому как и в паски играл (именно в такой, не уменьшительной форме), и с творожной пасхой одно время путался, называя кулич именно так. Меня из Харькова, от деда, перевезли в пятилетнем возрасте, а то, что харьковская семья была совсем не православных традиций (дед хоть и атеист был, но все-таки еврей), только добавляло мне путаницы.*

~2.
В Польше куличей, вроде, не пекут. А что пекут, то называют ciastka или wuzetka (последнее - с кремом). 
Про Белоруссию сказать сложно, все-таки сейчас там все говорят по-русски. 
Но вообще слово куліч в белорусском есть. Кажется, тут есть кто-то из Беларуси, надеюсь, подтвердят.

//======================

По поводу ягнёнка, пирогов и прочего.
Очень конспективно, ибо это совсем не языковые вопросы.

Первая пасхальная еда у евреев: мясо ягненка с мацой и горькими травами, ягненок был символом искупления (легко найдете в Интернете, что тут и как). На саму еду название "Пасха" (пейсах), насколько знаю, не переносили.
В христианстве "пасхальный" ягненок немножко изменил значение и стал символом жертвы Спасителя. Пасхальный кекс (не пирог) часто выпекали в форме ягненка. Возможно отсюда и версия, что *самого жертвенного ягненка* называли "пасхой". Ни один из этих фактов не объясняет ни переноса названия на еду, ни образования различия в значениях.

Про пасхальные пироги *в православной традиции* ничего не слышал, в Европе иногда на Пасху сладкие пироги пекут, но это местные традиции, причем даже там это все равно скорее торт, чем пирог. Впрочем, в кулинарных изысках я не настолько компетентен, может и вру.

Comment: Вообще-то, на Украине называют не пасКа, а пасХа. По крайней мере, я вариант с буквой К не слышала ни разу.

Comment: У нас на Дальнем Востоке тоже кулич называют пасхой. Наверное, потому, что в свое время было много переселенцев с Украины. Слово "кулич" стали понемногу употреблять (с каждым годом все больше) после публикаций в газетах и журналах (в последние 10-20 лет). А в песочнице лично я пекла пирожные.

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki Я тоже думала, что пасХа (на слух так и получается), но на покупных куличах написано "пасКа".

Comment: >на Украине называют не пасКа, а пасХа.  
...    
>но на покупных куличах написано "пасКа".      
    
Подтверждаю оба варианта. ПасКа и пасХа. Видимо, это просто фонетические варианты, зависит от района. Я специально даже не стал оговариваться.

Comment: По поводу переноса названия см. русские и церковно-славянские переводы Исход 12;11. У иудеев жертвенного ягнёнка называют корбан песах (пасхальная жертва). Наименование жертвы просто песах, тоже попадалось, но сомнительно, что это влияло на появление слова в русском. А вот отрывок из библии (точнее его интерпретация) на название данного блюда повлиял почти наверняка.

Comment: >Наименование жертвы просто песах,  
  
Нет. Жертва это как раз "корбан". А песах исходно означает "прошел мимо". 

>А вот отрывок из библии (точнее его интерпретация) на название данного блюда повлиял почти наверняка.  
  
Каким образом?

Comment: Я в курсе, что означает песах исходно, но называние пасхальной жертвы песахом мне попадалось. Например, [здесь](http://www.baruhaba.org.ua/?p=7334). Согласен, что это далеко не ортодоксы, но я писал, только про "попадалось".

А влияние самое непосредственное. Иисус - по христианским представлениям, это последняя пасхальная жертва на Пасху. Агнец божий, был пожертвован вместо агнца обычного. Кулич - это символ жертвы Христа, творожная пасха - символ гроба господня. В русской традиции корбан песах называют как раз пасхой. Наименование блюда пасхой связано с текстом Ветхого завета, а не иудаизмо

Answer (score 0):

На Украине сам праздник называется Пасха, выпекаем мы не кулич, а паску. Сырная паска у нас — это запеченный творог с добавлением масла, яиц, изюма (очень, очень вкусный). Сырная паска так же обязательно готовится на Пасху.

Comment: Вот ни разу не слышал, чтоб сам праздник (свято) в/на Украине назывался "Пасхой". Паска/пасха - это кулич. Сырная пасха -  да, это то, что пасхой называют в России.

Comment: — Сырная паска так же обязательно готовится на Пасху, — пишете. А когда же, если не к Пасхе?